# How to clearTimeout properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have this function that adds claps to a post. I don't want to add a clap with every clap because that would be insane on my mysql server, not to mention the http requests and re-renders. Instead, I want to let the claps add up a bit and only if the user stops adding claps for a few seconds, then add the claps to the database. So my function is storing the claps in state properly, but it is running the function every time and never clearing the timeout.

```
  let sendClapsToDB

  _clapForPost = (postId) => {

    clearTimeout(sendClapsToDB)

    setClaps(() => claps + 1)

    sendClapsToDB = setTimeout(() => {
      _addClapsToPost(claps, postID)
    }, 5000)
  }
```

Does anyone know how to do this properly. I am using React Native and fetch. The _clapForPost function is being called every time a user presses on a button.

Comment: one good practice is to reset to null the var is container, this method will push to garbage collector sendClapsToDB

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón - thanks for the attempt - but that didn't work.

Comment: Try with `var` instead of `let`. The variable `sendClapsToDB` in your example is in two different scopes. Maybe not the best solution, but it should be work!

Comment: @FrancescoSimeoli - tried it - did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a class component you can try something like this.

```js
import React from "react";


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {claps: 0}
  timeout = null;
  sendClap = () => {
    this.setState({claps: this.state.claps + 1})
    if(!this.timeout){
      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Send claps", this.state.claps);
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = null;
      }, 3000)
    }
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.state.claps);
    return <button onClick={this.sendClap}>Clap</button>

  }
}

export default App;
```

Im clearing the timer as it runs and re-initializing in the  next state update.
Also need to clear the timer when the component unmounts.

If you are using functional component with hooks, you can try something like

```js
import React, {useState, useRef} from "react";


export default () => {
  const [claps, setClaps] =  useState(0);
  const clapsRef = useRef(0);
  clapsRef.current = claps;
  const timeout = useRef(null);
  const sendClap = () => {
    setClaps(claps + 1);
    if(!timeout.current){
      timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Send claps", clapsRef.current);
        clearTimeout(timeout.current);
        timeout.current = null;
      }, 3000)
    }
  }

    console.log(claps);
    return <button onClick={sendClap}>Clap</button>

}
```

Here I'm using useState to re-render the component and useRef to capture the latest state for timeout to get the latest state reference.

Comment: I am using functional component using hooks - however, I tried converting your answer using setClapsTimeout(null) and then setting setClapsTimeout to the timeout function, but that did not work either. It was a little different in that it recorded the first clap to the db, then waited for the remaining claps and added them together. Not quite sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Updated the answer to use hooks. Let me know if this helps. Also please refer an article regarding use of timeouts in class and function component. A long article but probably worth it. (https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/)

Comment: I think this might have worked! I am heading to bed now, but will do more tests in the morning. If all is good I will mark as correct and get back to you. I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: This answer was excellent and worked great. I also read the article you referred and it was really helpful to understand why this worked, especially the part about using useRef. Thanks again!

Comment: I did find an edit that is needed... When the user starts clapping it sets the timer, which means it will run in 3 seconds no matter what. If the user is still clapping at after 3 seconds it will run the function and then run it again in another 3 seconds. To fix this I had to duplicate the `clearTimeout(timeout.current)` and `timeout.current = null` lines, to the beginning of the `sendClap` function so that it would setup the timeout function every time a person claps and it would not run until the user stops clapping for 3 seconds.